# why persistent check box in object store connector configuration is not enabled by default, if persistent store is default as per mule docs?

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I am new to mule and trying to implement object store.

**As per mule documentation:** 
*Mule provides two types of object stores:*

*In-memory store – Prior to Mule 3.5.0, in-memory store was the default. **As of Mule 3.5.0, persistent store is the default.** For more information, see "Object Stores and Clustering" in the Cache Scope document.*

*Persistent store – Mule persists data when an object store is explicitly configured to be persistent. Mule creates a default persistent store in the file system.*

it is mentioned as persistent store is default but in object store connector configuration persistent checkbox is not enabled by default. why it is so and which object store is used in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Note: Am using mule 3.8.3

[Screenshot of Object store configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oTvU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these are two different concepts. Mule Cache Scope which is what you are referring and Object Stores as a connector component itself.
If you are wrap a component in a cache scope then by default it uses 'default caching strategy' which uses inMemoryObjectStore (intended for testing only). It is better to store the cached responses in a separate store such as Object Store. Also, internally, Mule uses object stores in various filters, routers, and other message processors that need to store state between messages. In most cases, Mule creates and manages object stores automatically.

Coming to ObjectStores connector, they can be persisted to disk by proper configuration settings.

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: so Anand Ajjarapu, in object store connector if persistent check box is not selected then in this scenario, where does the object store reside?

Comment: Hi Arun,In a standalone environment or in on premises applications;, objectstore data is persisted on disk (typically at /.mule/<<application>>/objectstore/) however to persist data in Runtime Manager’s Application Data user interface, you need to use the _defaultUserObjectStore spring bean instance in your ObjectStore configuration.

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/object-store-connector#persistingdata